# drools.dump.dir property not dumping java version of drool file through api approach?

Tags: java, drools, rule-engine, kie

drools.dump.dir property not dumping java version of drool file through API approach ? i am using drool compiler version 6.1.0.Final

i have tried three approaches listed below :
1)

```
        KieBaseConfiguration kieBaseConfiguration= ks.newKieBaseConfiguration();

        kieBaseConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dump.dir","C:\ects\\dump");
        kieBaseConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dialect.default","JAVA");
        kContainer.newKieBase(kieBaseConfiguration);

2)     


KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration knowledgeBuilderConfiguration = 
       KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();
       knowledgeBuilderConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dump.dir","C:\\dump");



      knowledgeBuilderConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dialect.default","JAVA");

        KnowledgeBuilder knowledgeBuilder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder(knowledgeBuilderConfiguration);

        KnowledgeBase knowledgeBase= knowledgeBuilder.newKnowledgeBase();

        KieSession kSession = knowledgeBase.newKieSession();

3)      


        KieSessionConfiguration kieSessionConfiguration                                               =ks.newKieSessionConfiguration();
        kieSessionConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dump.dir","\\dump");
        kieSessionConfiguration.setProperty("drools.dialect.default","JAVA");*/

        KieSession kSession = kContainer.newKieSession(kieSessionConfiguration );
```

Comment: Set the property as system-level property by System.setProperty(DumpDirOption.PROPERTY_NAME, "folderlocation");

Comment: even this approach is not working , not able to find what is going wrong

Comment: It is working for me. Can you share your sample code along with  drl and java class?

Answer (score 0):

No official documentation about drools.dump.dir JVM property is available. I found an [interesting conversation](https://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/rules-users/2012-November/029502.html) around this in the drools mailing list. This property is meant to dump the .drl file when the rules are compiling from xls or drt form.

quoting the information below

> For ResourceType.DRL, the DumpDirOption isn't going to help. It is
> provided for compilations where the source is "pre-DRL", such as decision tables.